# How to tweak the font selection dialog preview (gnome3)

Tags: fonts, dialog, selection, gnome-3, fedora-25

The font selection dialog's preview mess up. How can I tweak it(maybe gsettings) or fix it.

Fedora 25. Gnome 3.

[font selection dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfAeo.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not "messed up" — you've simply chosen a font which does not have the characters you have asked it to preview. Instead, it's showing placeholder boxes with the unicode value. Solution: use a font with the character coverage you need.

Comment: So, how can I change the preview text?